# In ASP.NET Core 2.2 console application, is there a way to retain the httpcontext.connection.id for the entire user browser session

Tags: asp.net-core, console-application

Is there a way to retain the same value of the `httpcontext.connection.id` for the entire user browser session in a console application since the `connection.id` value changes when the page is refreshed or navigated to another page.

When I tried to use session variable in the console application, I get an error "Invalid operation".

Are there any other ways to retain the instance value throughout the browser session like `connection.id` etc.?

Comment: It might be useful to provide the console application code that you previously attempted to further illustrate how you've approached it.

Comment: To retrieve the connection id, Httpaccessor.httpcontext.connection.id- but the connection id changes when the page refreshes or navigated to another page. I want to retain the value. It need not be connection id , any concept that implement to retain the value when navigated to other page or links